# Can't stop kafka servers and zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have kafka brokers running and I want to stop kafka and zookeeper to bring some modifications and restart everything again (bring log.retention.hours to 4).
However the command : Kafka-server-stop doesn't seem to work ! 
In kafka-server-stop I have this :

```
PIDS=$(ps ax | grep -i 'kafka\.Kafka' | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')

if [ -z "$PIDS" ]; then
  echo "No kafka server to stop"
  exit 1
else
  kill SIGTERM $PIDS
fi
```

I've tried to kill kafka servers processus with "kill -9" but each time it restarts with another PID. 
How can I restart everything ? Stop kafka and zookeeper to restart again.

**EDIT :**

When I run : ps aux | grep kafka , 
I get something like this :

```
root      6303  2.9 14.6 4861140 1174552 pts/0 Sl   16:26   0:53 /.../kafka-connect-fs-0.2-SNAPSHOT-package/share/java/kafka-c
root      7710  1.3  2.4 3061164 192612 pts/2  Sl+  16:28   0:23 /.../kafka-connect-fs/c
root     12008  0.4 11.3 3654604 907448 ?      Sl   Jun02  65:11 /.../kafka-connect-fs-0.2-SNAPSHOT-package/share/java/kafka-c
root     13838  0.0  0.0 112656   936 pts/1    R+   16:56   0:00 grep --color=auto kafka
root     26192  0.1  5.0 3062204 401224 ?      Sl   Jun02  25:34 /.../kafka-connect-fs-0.2-SNAPSHOT-package/share/java/kafka
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the version are you using ?
I'm on the 0.10.1.0 and the script works but in any case it's for stopping only the Kafka server and not the Zookeeper as well.
The first difference I notice with the script you posted is that mine has :

kill -s TERM $PIDS

that is a fix for this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3384 made to be POSIX compliant.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I'm using kafka 0.10.2.0, I changed the script to have "kill -s TERM $PIDS" but I still get : "No kafka server to stop"
And when I use this command to list the brokers : zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids", I get my brokers [0,1,2]

Comment: Can you execute just the first command of the script on the command line ? so ... ps ax | grep -i 'kafka\.Kafka' | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' What is the result ?

Comment: But I get a result when using : ps aux | grep server.properties

Comment: And with your command can you see "kafka.Kafka config/server.properties" as latest information ?

Comment: And with your command can you see "kafka.Kafka config/server.properties" as latest information ?

Comment: With the previous command, I get this : root     25450  0.0  0.0 112652   940 pts/2    S+   15:36   0:00 grep --color=auto server.properties

Comment: So you don't have Kafka running on the host you are executing your command. With your simple ps aux finding for regular expressions with server.properties you should have a long output for the running Kafka process with a PID and finally something like "kafka.Kafka config/server.properties". The script is right, it seems you don't have a Kafka server running on the host.

Comment: I see ! But do you know why ? To start the kafka servers I used : " kafka-server-start.sh server.properties & "

Comment: When you do that from the console, can you see the output log from the Kafka server while it's starting ?

Comment: Interesting ... trying executing ps aux | grep kafka ... what's the output ?

Comment: I displayed the result in my post (EDIT)

Comment: I don't see the Kafka server running but only Kafka Connect. What are you trying to do ? can you shutdown Kafka Connect and just executing zookeeper and the kafka server on your machine ?

Comment: Kafka connect is here because it was running before ( I could produce and consume messages, send them to spark streaming...) then I wanted to clean my topics and change the retention time. I wanted to stop the brokers and restart them so the modification can take effect. I actually killed kafka connect process and restarted zookeeper and Kafka, it works ! Thank you for your time